# Imagenes no se muestran a pesar de tener la ruta correcta en HTML

Tags: html, laravel

Estoy haciendo un sitio web con laravel y estoy comenzando una "versión de pruebas" de una página de usuario. Al momento de poner el link a la imagen de usuario, uso:

```
<img src="../public/testing_images/user_icon.jpg">
```

Y en las carpetas, el archivo esta en:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También probé usando:

```
<img src="/public/testing_images/user_icon.jpg">

<img src="public/testing_images/user_icon.jpg">

<img src="../ruleta/public/testing_images/user_icon.jpg">

<img src="../../public/testing_images/user_icon.jpg">
```

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal? ¿o esto es propio de laravel?

Comment: qué error te da?

Comment: Básicamente la imagen no aparece, 404 not found

Comment: puedes usar la dirección absoluta, o la relativa, prueba con la absoluta

Comment: tambien puedes probar con el explorador de windows

Comment: puedes hacerlo asi:  `<img src="{{ URL::asset('testing_images/user_icon.jpg') }}">` o asi `{{ HTML::image('testing_images/user_icon.jpg') }}` para ver si te sigue saliendo??

Comment: Probe con la absoluta y...no sirvio, igual gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba usando el *helper* [`asset`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset) para construir de este modo la ruta que invoque a tu imagen:

```
<img src="{{ asset('testing_images/user_icon.jpg') }}" />
```

De modo que no escribes tu explícitamente la ruta sino que el *helper* se encarga de completarla, necesitas indicarle la carpeta que contiene tus imágenes y el recurso a obtener de ella

Comment: Funciona !!!

Muchas gracias!!